# jquery tab displaying problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

how to get rid of the orange background image in the tabs???

**EDIT**

i tried

```
 $('.ul').removeClass('ui-widget-header ');
        $('.li').removeClass('ui-widget-header ');
       $('div[id^=tab]').removeClass('ui-widget-header');
        $('a').removeClass('ui-widget-header');
```

but no result!

Comment: give us some context for this question - are you talking about these tabs? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll probably want to check out various themes for jQuery UI. It sounds like you're using the default one. There is the theme roller where you can create your own that will match your app better.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change your theme using [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) or, comment out the CSS, but note this will affect your other header styles:

Comment out this line, around line 54 in the CSS might have moved a bit:

```
.ui-widget-header { .... }
```